# Finding minimum value in array of doubles

Tags: java

I have this method where I find the distances with an Euclidean algorithm and save the values as double in an array of doubles. Now I need to find the minimum value of each test and return the value indexed.

```
    public static double distance() {

    for (int i = 0; i < GetFile.testMatrix.length;) {

        double[] distances = new double[4000];
        double minDistance = 999999;
        for (int j = 0; j < GetFile.trainingMatrix.length; j++) {
            distances[j] = EuclideanDistance.findED(GetFile.trainingMatrix[j], GetFile.testMatrix[i]);
        }

        return minDistance;
    }
    return 0;

}
```

I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please clarify how you'd like the output to look?

Comment: saved to a simple txt file wouldnt mind...thx

Comment: I wasn't asking on where you want it saved, I was trying to get some clarity on what you were trying to achieve - a single, minimal double from an array? Something more complicated?

Comment: Any problems with `Math.min(a,b)` or `if(a < min) { min = a; }` ?

Comment: I would like to return a minimum double value for every distance value stored in double[] distances... would something like this work??                      minDistance = Math.min(j, distances[j]);

Comment: Also please make your arrays more with generic length (e.g. `distances = new double[GetFile.trrainingmatrix.length];` and if you want to set minDistance to something (which is bad style!) you should choose Double.MAX_VALUE

Comment: @user2288769 In your example snippet, the arguments to Math.min should be minDistance =  Math.min(minDistance, distances[j]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way along with your code:

```
public static double distance() {

    for (int i = 0; i < GetFile.testMatrix.length;) {

        double[] distances = new double[4000];
        for (int j = 0; j < GetFile.trainingMatrix.length; j++) {
            distances[j] = EuclideanDistance.findED(GetFile.trainingMatrix[j], GetFile.testMatrix[i]);
        }

        return getMinDistance(distances);
    }
    return 0;

}


static double getMinDistance(double[] distances) {
    double minDistance = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    for (double distance : distances) {
        minDistance = Math.min(distance, minDistance);
    }
    return minDistance;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look as though you need to store the result in an array at all, since that's being discarded. You should consider tracking the result in minDistance every time you get a result from findED.

This also looks like the kind of thing that would be a lot easier to understand if you used java's streams, if you're using a version of java that has access to them.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do so.
One way would be iterating over the values and taking always the smallest:

```
double minDistance = distances[0];
for(int j =1 ;j < GetFile.trainingMatrix.length; j++){
    if(distances[j]<minDistance)
        minDistance=distances[j];
}
```

or alternatively

```
double minDistance = distances[0];
for(int j =1 ;j < GetFile.trainingMatrix.length; j++){
    minDistance = Math.min(minDistance, distances[j];
}
```

or using streams (with distances as List):

```
double minDistance = distances.stream().mapToDouble(e -> e).min().getAsDouble();
```

or even nicer (with your for-loop completely implemented):

```
double minDistance = Stream.iterate(0,j -> j+1)
                           .limit(GetFile.trainingMatrix.length)
                           .mapToDouble(j->EuclideanDistance.findED(GetFile.trainingMatrix[j], GetFile.testMatrix[i]))
                           .min().orElse(-1);
```

Comment: `min()` will return an Optional, check with `ifPresent()` first no?

Comment: @YassinHajaj Because of that there is a getAsDouble(); This will throw an exception, if there is no element. Alternativley would be .orElse(42);

Answer (score 0):

Assign the minDistance to distances[0] unless you are very sure about the maximum value that distances array will contain.

```
public static double distance() {

    for (int i = 0; i < GetFile.testMatrix.length;) {

    double[] distances = new double[4000];
    double minDistance;
    for (int j = 0; j < GetFile.trainingMatrix.length; j++) {
        distances[j] = EuclideanDistance.findED(GetFile.trainingMatrix[j], GetFile.testMatrix[i]);
    }

    minDistance = distances[0];
    for(int i = 1 ; i < distances.length; i++)  {
         if(minDistance > distances[i])    {
              minDistance = distances[i];
         }
    }

    return minDistance;
}
```